# How to magnify images of the products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, zoom

I would like to know how to enlarge the images on the pages of products.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `theme/template/catalog/view/media.phtml` and change this

```
<img id="image-main"
            itemprop="image"
             class="gallery-image visible"
             src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />
```

to

```
<?php echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(true)->resize(1035, 692).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'"/>';?>
```

See this `resize(1035, 692)` section, it is telling that make image's size to 1035px × 692px.

Hope this helps.

Comment: in what file I have to put this code?

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: if you need a dynamic magnify, have a look at https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/ (wok very well)